# TextInputLayout change width when error occurred

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I Have the **LinearLayout** with two nested **TextInputLayout**.

When there is no error, then everything is OK.
[image]
But when an error occurs, the size of the **TextInputLayout** changes. 
[image]
Tell me please, what am I doing wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:baselineAligned="false"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputPower"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

         <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editText3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:digits=".0123456789"
          android:hint="Мощность (W)"
          android:inputType="numberDecimal"
          android:maxLength="10"
          android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
          android:textSize="14sp" />
         </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

          <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/textInputAmperage"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:digits=".0123456789"
             android:hint="Ток (А)"
             android:inputType="numberDecimal"
             android:maxLength="10"
             android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
             android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use weight sum for linear layout.

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputPower"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits=".0123456789"
            android:hint="Мощность (W)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputAmperage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits=".0123456789"
            android:hint="Ток (А)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help

Comment: you can try it now.

Comment: Now everything is fine. Thank you so much. To vote for an answer, I don't have enough 4 points of reputation.

Comment: maybe you can help me one more time? See at this screen (everything is OK) - https://pp.vk.me/c639323/v639323288/61d7/TCfnkm8aGoE.jpg and to this  - https://pp.vk.me/c639323/v639323288/61e1/odgciCldMGg.jpg . With error msg in second row height of CardView increases. How can I fix this?